# Adding a WinForm control to a Word Document using VSTO

Tags: winforms, ms-word, label, controls, vsto

I'd like to add labels to my Word document, specifically in the margin. I've seen that things like date pickers and combo boxes can be added to the document, but I can't see anything for what I'm after.

I can get the ControlCollection object via:

```
Globals.Factory.GetVstoObject(myApplication.ActiveDocument).Controls
```

but there are no methods for adding labels.

Are there any alternative methods for adding labels to a document using VSTO?

[EDIT]

So I managed to insert WinForm labels, however it is extremely slow, as is confirmed in this post:

http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/277090/adding-winform-controls-to-a-vsto-word-document-is-extremely-slow

So I'm still looking for alternatives. I cannot find any label-like ContentControls as suggested in the thread above.

Comment: What are you looking for that `ActiveDocument.ContentControls.Add(wdContentControlText)` doesn't do?

Comment: So what I want is to be able to place the label into the document without shifting anything. I also don't have the freedom to place a wdContentControlText in places such as the margin.

Comment: Can you insert a comment, and then insert a text control into the comment?

Comment: A comment still is not ideal, as it can only stay in the margin in specific positions, not allowing the flexibility of placing it wherever I need it to be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the solution that I settled on was to use Word shapes. The snippet of code below shows how to add a label shape to your document.

```
Shape shape = 
   doc.Shapes.AddLabel(Office.MsoTextOrientation.msoTextOrientationHorizontal,
                                                                         left,
                                                                          top,
                                                                        width,
                                                                       height,
                                                                        range);
```

The process of adding multiple labels is by no means lightning fast, but is significantly faster than adding the winform controls to the document. Shapes give you the flexibility to place it wherever you want on the page too, which is something that ContentControls do not offer.